# Trying to convert a complex nested JSON schema into an Excel spreadsheet or CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, nested

I am trying to convert a complex JSON schema into a simple spreadsheet using python. My JSON looks like this

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "DataElement1": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "SUCCESS",
        "ERROR"
      ],
      "description": "XXXXX."
    },
    "DataElement2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DataElement3": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "YYYYYY"
        },
        "DataElement4": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "ZZZZZZ."
        }
      },
      "description": "AAAAAAAA"
    },
    "DataElement5": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DataElement6": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "BBBBBBB"
        },
        "DataElement7": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "CCCCCCCC"
        },
        "DataElement8": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "DDDDDDDDD"
        },
         "required": [
        "DataElement6"
        ],
        "description": "EEEEEEEEEEE"
    }
 },
     "required": [
        "DataElement1",
        "DataElement2"
        ]
  
 }
}
```

The output should just have 4 columns with all different data elements listed like mentioned below. The nested data elements should be listed along with the parent data element group.

```
Data Element                | Type   | Description  | Required
DataElement1                | string | XXXX         | DataElement1
DataElement2                | string | AAAA         | DataElement2
DataElement2.DataElement3   | string | YYYY         | 
DataElement2.DataElement4   | string | ZZZZ         | 
DataElement5                | number |  EEEE        | 
DataElement5.DataElement6   | number |  BBBB        | DataElement6
DataElement5.DataElement7   | string |  CCCC        | 
DataElement5.DataElement8   | number |  DDDD        |
```

Could anyone help sharing an approach to convert this JSON to a csv format using Python ?

Thank you for the help !

---

**

Comment: Have you tried nothing at all?  This is not a code writing service.  And that is NOT a "complex JSON".

Comment: Surely DataElement2 and DataElement5 should have Type == 'object'.

Comment: A “schema” describes data - it isn’t “actual” data, so it can’t be turned into anything but a set of excel/CSV headers without rows of actual data, i.e. it is a description of the columns which would be populated with data which conforms to the schema.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am fairly new to python coding. The approach I took was to flatten the complete schema file and then map the rows to csv header columns. I was able to flatten the file but mapping them to the columns was becoming challenging.  Maybe the approach itself was incorrect..  I was able to get the below output -



type : object
properties.DataElement1.type : string
properties.DataElement1.enum[0] : SUCCESS
properties.DataElement1.enum[1] : ERROR
properties.DataElement1.description : XXXXX.
properties.DataElement2.type : object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:  (*You would have to tweak a bit*)

```
d = { ... your JSON structure ...} 

df = pd.json_normalize(d)
scols = pd.Series(df.columns.to_list()).str.replace('properties\\.','')
df.columns = scols.to_list()
tgt_cols = scols[scols.str.contains('DataElement') & (scols.str.contains('desc') | scols.str.contains('type') | scols.str.contains('required'))]

nd = {}

for x in tgt_cols:
    field = x.split(r'.')[-1]
    data_element = x.replace('.'+field, '')
    
    if data_element not in nd:
        nd[data_element] = {'Data Element': data_element}
        
    nd[data_element][field] = df.loc[0][x]

pd.DataFrame(list(nd.values()))

                Data Element    type  description        required
0               DataElement1  string       XXXXX.             NaN
1               DataElement2  object     AAAAAAAA             NaN
2  DataElement2.DataElement3  string       YYYYYY             NaN
3  DataElement2.DataElement4  string      ZZZZZZ.             NaN
4               DataElement5  object  EEEEEEEEEEE  [DataElement6]
5  DataElement5.DataElement6  number      BBBBBBB             NaN
6  DataElement5.DataElement7  string     CCCCCCCC             NaN
7  DataElement5.DataElement8  number    DDDDDDDDD             NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want.

```
data = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "DataElement1": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "SUCCESS",
        "ERROR"
      ],
      "description": "XXXXX."
    },
    "DataElement2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DataElement3": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "YYYYYY"
        },
        "DataElement4": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "ZZZZZZ."
        }
      },
      "description": "AAAAAAAA"
    },
    "DataElement5": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "DataElement6": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "BBBBBBB"
        },
        "DataElement7": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "CCCCCCCC"
        },
        "DataElement8": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "DDDDDDDDD"
        },
         "required": [
            "DataElement6"
        ]
      },
      "description": "EEEEEEEEEEE"
    },
     "required": [
        "DataElement1",
        "DataElement2"
        ]
  }
}

def handle_object( prefix, obj ):
    required = []
    if 'required' in obj['properties']:
        required = obj['properties']['required']
    for k,v in obj['properties'].items():
        if not isinstance(v,dict):
            continue
        name = '.'.join((prefix,k)) if prefix else k
        reqd = k if k in required else ''
        print( ','.join((name, v['type'], v['description'], reqd )))

        if v['type'] == 'object':
            handle_object( k, v )

print("Data Element,Type,Description,Required")
handle_object( '', data )
```

Output:

```
Data Element,Type,Description,Required
DataElement1,string,XXXXX.,DataElement1
DataElement2,object,AAAAAAAA,DataElement2
DataElement2.DataElement3,string,YYYYYY,
DataElement2.DataElement4,string,ZZZZZZ.,
DataElement5,object,EEEEEEEEEEE,
DataElement5.DataElement6,number,BBBBBBB,DataElement6
DataElement5.DataElement7,string,CCCCCCCC,
DataElement5.DataElement8,number,DDDDDDDDD,
```